# Storing image file in postgresql table failed

Tags: php, html, postgresql, image, upload

I am trying to store an image file in a psql database table. The table 'images' has two fields, 'id' of type integer & 'image' of type bytea.

I tried to modify image saving code from a tutorial on web. But my code is raising error & warning.

Here is the error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\maps\un.php on line 48

Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\maps\un.php on line 50
cannot read image
```

These errors are on lines inside `if(isset($_POST["submit1"])){` block

How to correct these errors ?

**Here is my code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Image Upload</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<?php
require("connection.php");
?>

<div class="container-fluid">
          <h1 align="center">Test Form </h1>

   <form action="" method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <h2> Field </h2>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom01">Field ID</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="field_id" id="field_id" placeholder="insert field id" value="" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        0
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom02">IMG</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="image" placeholder="insert image" value="" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">

      </div>
    </div>      
   </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit1" type="submit">Insert Image</button>
</form>


    <?php

          if(isset($_POST["submit1"])){

              $file_name = $_POST["image"];

              $img = fopen($file_name, 'r') or die("cannot read image\n");
              $data = fread($img, filesize($file_name));

              $es_data = pg_escape_bytea($data);
              fclose($img);   


            try {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO images (field_id, image)
                VALUES ('".$_POST["field_id"]."','.$es_data.')";
                 // echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
                if ($conn->query($sql)) {
                     echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
                          }
                          else{
                            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully Inserted.');</script>";
                      }
                            $dbh = null;
                    }
                        catch(PDOException $e)
                    {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                        }
                    }   

                    //$conn = null;

                    ?>

    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you wanna store the whole image in a db? Why not only store the path?

Comment: @Lithilion: Because the images are of not high resolution & not in high quantity.

Comment: But storing images in a db really slows it down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files are stored in the `$_FILES` superglobal. There is no image in the `$_POST`.
The filename will be `$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]`. This is the path where php temporarily uploads it and you can handle it.

Ref: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

PS: Your code is vulnerable to SQL-Injection. Please use Prepared Statements or PDO.

Comment: Thank you: Undefined index: image error gone but this warning exists:
Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\maps\un.php on line 50 cannot read image. Line 50 is:
$data = fread($img, filesize($file_name));

Comment: Are you sure its the right line? It says something about fopen, but its not in the line you showed

Comment: Sorry;  $img = fopen($file_name, 'r') or die("cannot read image\n");

Comment: can you `var_dump($file_name)`?

Comment: Execute it before line 50 and comment the lines below.

Comment: array(5) { ["name"]=> string(8) "user.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php30F5.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(449278) }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183175/discussion-between-lithilion-and-xceptable).